# AAD Token Cache - How to utilize Azure Table Storage as a token store

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, adal, azure-ad-msal

I have developed a web app that uses Azure Active Directory to authenticate. The application is redirected to AAD, which after authentication, stores a token in a token cache provided by the application. The app then uses Entity framework to retrieve the token, using the location provided by default location, and by default this points to the local database.

My question - is there any way I can change the location of the token store to either a table service or the application cache provided by Azure. I think this will involve configuration on the Active Directory as well as changing the method that retrieves the token.

Are there any open source libraries that will let me do this?  Also, are there any publicly available samples that demonstrate this process?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the custom token cache provided by MSAL.In custom token cache, retrive the token and then make an api call to store it anywhere you want.

Here is the api detail
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/token-cache-serialization

Here is a sample use of the custom token cache
https://github.com/agrabhi/active-directory-b2c-graph-trustframework-policy/blob/master/console-csharp-trustFrameworkPolicy/TokenCacheHelper.cs

Curious, why would you want to store customer tokens though.